# Is it posible to use cancan methods in activeadmin initializer, specially to render menu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activeadmin, cancan

In activeadmin initializer I add aditional item in utility_navigation(right_part). Here is the code:

```
config.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.build_menu :utility_navigation do |menu|
    menu.add label: I18n.t('active_admin.menu.import'), url: '/admin/import'
    admin.add_logout_button_to_menu menu
  end
end
```

How can I use can? method for check access when building menu? I think, in config cancan does not initialized yet.

Answer (score 0):

In short - RTM
http://activeadmin.info/docs/13-authorization-adapter.html#using_the_cancan_adapter
(yes, you can...)

Comment: Hmm, do you see, that I mean initializer file and not just simple page?

Answer (score 0):

Menu items can be shown or hidden at runtime using the :if option.

```
    menu.add label: I18n.t('active_admin.menu.import'), url: '/admin/import', if: proc{ current_user.admin? } #or use any cancan magic.
```

The proc will be called in the context of the view, so you have access to all your helpers and current user session information.

[Activeadmin Doc](http://activeadmin.info/docs/2-resource-customization.html#conditionally-showing-/-hiding-menu-items)